# Can't checkout when remove country field

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, country-regions

I tried to hide the **country field** in the checkout page and billing page.
Here's my code :

```
<item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
<item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

I could do checkout when i remove this code :

```
<item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

But, when i remove it, the country field still appeared. How can i hide the country field? I can't hide with CSS because the class for country field is `class="field _required"`

Comment: why do you want to remove?

Comment: cause it's only in my country, and it should be default choose only 1 country

Comment: .fieldset.address div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"] {display: none;}

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using plugin:

```
  $visible = [
       'visible' => false
       ];

  $country = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps'] 
 ['children']['shipping-step']
['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset'] 
 ['children']['country_id'];

  $street = array_merge($country, $visible);
```

Comment: @AdityaShah @ Rutvee please be kind to each other. You are both wonderful people for helping out others with answers to their questions

Comment: hi @RutveeSojitra, i tried your pluggin, but it made the checkout page just blank, is there something wrong i did?

Comment: It's work for me, you just need to pass `['children']['company']['visible'] = false` if you want to hide company field. +1 for this :)